# ScrollView of react-native clashes for playlist in react-native-youtube-iframe. How to solve this?

Tags: react-native

here I am using bottomsheetmodal , under that bottomsheetscrollview and youtube.

```
import YoutubePlayer from 'react-native-youtube-iframe';
import BottomSheet, {
  BottomSheetModal,
  useBottomSheetModal,
  BottomSheetScrollView,
} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

  <BottomSheetModal
        ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        backgroundStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          borderTopLeftRadius: 24,
          borderTopRightRadius: 24,
          marginHorizontal: 4,
        }}>
        <BottomSheetScrollView
          keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never"
          horizontal={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        > 

          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, marginHorizontal: 8}}>
            <YoutubePlayer
              height={300}
              width={'100%'}
              playList={['b6PimS7dtW8', '4jW9wk_g9QY','31p9_4fu9mw','Zco3XlYt6Ko']}
              playListStartIndex={0}
              webViewProps={{
                androidLayerType: 'hardware',
            }}
            />
          </View>
        </BottomSheetScrollView>
       
      </BottomSheetModal>
```

[image]

when I am not using the ScrollView then the scroll is working. I have used zindex:999 in View style but nothing works.`